# Flow: How to declare that a type implements an interface?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to declare that a variable is a constructor that implements an interface, but I can't figure out how:

[try flow link](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIBGcUAFAJQBcyAbusACYDcuAvrrggDZwDOvyAEIlkwALYAHLhDERwAjFjwFiZctnbtO6ELzDIEOvVACuCMOijVSFZAF4AfGkzl7QkkyA)

```js
interface Foo {
  bar(): void;
}

class Bar implements Foo {
  bar(){}
}

const constructor: (() => Foo) = Bar;
```

The last line doesn't work as intended, but it's hopefully clear what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

```js
const constructor: Class<Foo> = Bar;
```